# Replace numpy subarray when element matches a condition

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an `n x m x 3` numpy array. This represents a middle-step towards an RGB representation of a complex-function plotter. When the function being plotted takes infinite values or has singularities, parts of the RGB data become NaNs.

I'm looking for an efficient way to replace a row containing a NaN with a row of my choice, perhaps `[0, 0, 0]` or `[1, 1, 1]`. In terms of the RGB values, this has the effect of replacing poorly-behaving pixels with white or black pixels. By *efficient*, I mean some way that takes advantage of numpy's vectorization and speed.

Please note that I am not looking to merely replace the NaN values with 0 (which I know how to do with `numpy.where`); if a row contains a NaN, I want to replace the whole row. I suspect this can be done nicely in numpy, but I'm not sure how.

### Concrete Question

Suppose we are given a `2 x 2 x 3` array `arr`. If a row contains a 5, I want to replace the row with `[0, 0, 0]`. Trivial code that does this slowly is as follows.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]])

# so arr is
# array([[[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6]],
#
#       [[1, 3, 5],
#        [2, 4, 6]]])

# Trivial and slow version to replace rows containing 5 with [0,0,0]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        if 5 in arr[i][j]:
            arr[i][j] = np.array([0, 0, 0])

# Now arr is
#
# array([[[1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 0, 0]],
#
#       [[0, 0, 0],
#        [2, 4, 6]]])
```

How can we accomplish this taking advantage of numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way would be -

```
arr[np.isin(arr,5).any(-1)] = 0
```

If it's just a single value that you are looking for, then we could simplify to -

```
arr[(arr==5).any(-1)] = 0
```

If you are looking to match against `NaN`, we need to do the comparison differently and use `np.isnan` instead -

```
arr[np.isnan(arr).any(-1)] = 0
```

If you are looking to assign array values, instead of just `0`, the solutions stay the same. Hence it would be -

```
arr[(arr==5).any(-1)] = new_array
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html)

```
arr[np.broadcast_to((arr == 5).any(-1)[..., None], arr.shape)] = 0
```

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [2, 4, 6]]])
```

---

Just as FYI, based on your description, if you want to find `np.nan`s instead of integers like `5`, you shouldn't use `==`, but rather `np.isnan`

```
arr[np.broadcast_to((np.isnan(arr)).any(-1)[..., None], arr.shape)] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using in1d function like below

```py
arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]])

arr[np.in1d(arr,5).reshape(arr.shape).any(axis=2)] = [0,0,0]
arr
```